# NSTimer not stopping when invalidated in this function

Tags: swift, nstimer

I'm trying to use NTTimer but it doesn't work.

It is started here:

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.003, target: self, selector: "openFrameAnimation", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

It fires this function:

```
func openFrameAnimation(){
    Swift.print("Animation Goes... ",NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
    self.frame = NSRect(x: self.frame.origin.x,
        y: self.frame.origin.y-12,
        width: self.frame.width,
        height: self.frame.height + 12)
    if(self.frame.height >= self.finalFrame.height){
        Swift.print("STOP")
        self.frame = self.finalFrame
        timer.invalidate()
        // timer = nil //ERROR: nil cannot be assigned to type "NSTimer"
    }
    self.needsDisplay = true
}
```

Even if "STOP" is printed over and over again, the timer continues to call openFrameAnimation and I can't stop it. How can I stop timer when condition is verified?

Log:

```
[...]
*Animation Goes...  1456613095.27813
STOP
[...]
Animation Goes...  1456613095.51233
STOP
Animation Goes...  1456613095.54458
[...]
STOP
Animation Goes...  1456613095.5938
STOP*
```

Comment: What you show should work. You need to provide more background. Where is the code that starts the timer? (In what method) Show the containing method, and tell us how it is called. Where is timer defined? My guess is that you're creating more than one timer, and then only that last one created is referenced in the "timer" variable.

Comment: You should rewrite your timer method openFrameAnimation to take an NSTimer as a parameter (The timer that fired to call the method.) That's the normal method signature for a timer method. You could then log the timer to see what's going on.

Comment: I'd suggest using `CADisplayLink` rather than `NSTimer` for animations. It's optimally timed for animations (fires at the earliest possible time for purposes of animating). See https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=236 (about 14 min in) for discussion on this topic. FWIW, even if you stayed with `NSTimer`, there's no point in running a timer every 0.003 seconds, as the max frame rate is 60 fps, i.e. roughly every 0.01667 seconds. Also, regarding your setting the timer variable to `nil`, you can make it an optional and you'll be able to set it to `nil` and release the old timer.

Answer (score 15):

Swift 4

1. add

   ```
   var timer = Timer()
   ```

to the top of the class

2. set your timer (using your original info - you may want to change as per some suggestions, particularly the one from @Rob about the frame rate)

   ```
   timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.003, target: self, selector: #selector("openFrameAnimation"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
   ```
3. stop the timer

   ```
       timer.invalidate()
       timer = Timer()
   ```

Comment: @Moebius - this answer has helped several, so I suggest you check your setup to make sure you have changed to your local settings (i.e., it is not likely you have "openFrameAnimiation" as a selector...)  You might also want to start your own question with more details of what you are using so someone can more specifically help you.

Comment: Why do you need to call set timer = Timer() in the stop function? Shouldn't timer.invalidate() be enough to stop it? What does invalidate() do exactly?

Comment: @JDune timer.invalidate() removes 'Timer()' from the 'timer' variable, so you have to reinitialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Check and make sure you're not creating the timer multiple times in a row. This can cause the reference to the original timer to be lost.

Doing this right before you create the timer can help.

```
guard timer == nil else {
    return
}
```