# Using Swift 3 Stopping a scheduledTimer, Timer continue firing even if timer is nil

Tags: timer, swift3

We call startTimer function to start a timer. When we wanted to stop it we call stopTimerTest function but after we called stopTimer function the timerTestAction keeps firing. To check the timer condition we used print and print in timerActionTest returns nil.

```
var timerTest: Timer? = nil

func startTimer () {
    timerTest =  Timer.scheduledTimer(
        timeInterval: TimeInterval(0.3),
        target      : self,
        selector    : #selector(ViewController.timerActionTest),
        userInfo    : nil,
        repeats     : true)
}

func timerActionTest() {
    print(" timer condition \(timerTest)")
}

func stopTimerTest() {
    timerTest.invalidate()
    timerTest = nil
}
```

Comment: try to declare `var timerTest : Timer?` then in `startTimer` before instantiating add `if timerTest == nil { your instantiation}` and in `stopTimerTest` add  `if timerTest != nil { your code}`

Comment: **if timerTest == nil { your instantiation}**  is made the day brighter.

Comment: can you post some code which compiles has suggested by Vadian?

Comment: Mr. @mat your comment is the answer my question. If you can make it an answer I can check it as answer. If you want of course, no pressure.

Comment: @Hope I am glad it fixed your problem. I have just answered.

Comment: A cleaner, Swift 4 approach can be found in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35676407/nstimer-not-stopping-when-invalidated-in-this-function).

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Try to make the following changes to your code:

First, you have to change the way you declare `timerTest`

```
var timerTest : Timer?
```

then in `startTimer` before instantiating check if `timerTest` is nil

```
func startTimer () {
  guard timerTest == nil else { return }

  timerTest =  Timer.scheduledTimer(
      timeInterval: TimeInterval(0.3),
      target      : self,
      selector    : #selector(ViewController.timerActionTest),
      userInfo    : nil,
      repeats     : true)
}
```

Finally in your `stopTimerTest` you invalidate `timerTest` if it isn't nil

```
func stopTimerTest() {
  timerTest?.invalidate()
  timerTest = nil
}
```

Comment: remember null safe timerTest?.invalidate(), one line

Comment: A cleaner, Swift 4 approach can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35676407/nstimer-not-stopping-when-invalidated-in-this-function

Comment: that's funny. I didn't know people had started to "advertise" their own answers! ;)

Comment: `guard timerTest == nil else { return }` is important

Answer (score 45):

Most likely you've called `startTimer` twice without calling `stopTimerTest`. If you do that, you'll lose your pointer to the original timer and never be able to invalidate it.

The typical approach is to manage invalidation as a part of setting:

```
var timerTest : Timer? = nil {
    willSet {
        timerTest?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Then stopping is just setting to nil:

```
func stopTimerTest() {
    timerTest = nil
}
```

Comment: I also assumed that it would call invalidate upon resetting it's value ... nice solution ... could also use an extension :)

Comment: This is my problem => "you'll lose your pointer to the original timer and never be able to invalidate it". Thanks

Comment: This is the most elegant solution for timer invalidation. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 12):

Make sure when you call `StartTimer` it is `nil` and if you call `StartTimer` twice without calling `StopTimer`. You will lose your original pointer and you can't stop it.

```
 var timer : Timer? = nil {
        willSet {
            timer?.invalidate()
        }
    }
```

Start and Stop timer like ...

```
func startTimer() {
    stopTimer()
    guard self.timer == nil else { return }
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10, target: self, selector: #selector(self.fetchData), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func stopTimer() {
    guard timer != nil else { return }
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Check, are you really call `stopTimerTest()`, because `timerTest.invalidate()` is correct for stopping timer.

```
func stopTimerTest() {
    print("stopTimer")
    timerTest.invalidate()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Full working code

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {


var timer:Timer? = nil
var countValue = 60;


@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    self.timer?.invalidate()
    self.timer = nil
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(countDown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc
func countDown() {
    if countValue>1 {
        countValue -= 1
    } else {
        self.timer?.invalidate()
        self.timer = nil
    }
    print("\(countValue) Seconds")
}}
```